# Unhandled Rejection (Type Error): Object(..) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js

My code

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { legacy_createStore as createStore } from "redux";

const counterReducer = (state = { counter: 0, counter1: 0 }, action) => {
  if (action.type === "increment") {
    return {
      ...state,
      counter1: state.counter + 1
    };
  }
  if (action.type === "decrement") {
    return {
      ...state,
      counter: state.counter - 1
    };
  }
  return state;
};

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const myStore = createStore(counterReducer);
  return (
    <Provider store={myStore}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Throwing error as follows

[image]

How to address it? You can run it below:

[image: Edit nextjs redux-react-hooks (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the version of react that you are using. I don't think legacy_createStore was introduced until version 4.2

Comment: The error still there if you changed it to `import { createStore } from "redux"`, you can try on the codesandbox

Comment: I changed it to createStore and it clears the error. You have other errors with exporting useDispatch and useSelector not exporting correctly from react-redux